# Who are in the current top 10-20 applied mathematics educators and in what fields?

Tags: applied-mathematics, teachers

Who are in the current top 10-20 applied mathematics educators and in what fields? (Answers will be varied)

Applied mathematics educators that teaches applied math topics such as applied statistics, differential equations, etc and are also have good influence in industry or organization or research.  Terrence Tao is not one example, because he is pure mathematician. Gilbert Strang is also not an example in this context.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "applied mathematics educators"?

Comment: Your question is very vague.  What is "current"?  (past five years?  past three decades?)  What is "top"?  (The smartest?  The most famous?  The one with the most publications?  The one with the most awards?)

Comment: Do you consider arithmetic, algebra, geometry, and trigonometry to be applied mathematics?  Do we include educators from primary and secondary education?

Comment: Following up on @quid we could consider "(applied mathematics) educators" or "applied (mathematics educators)". The former teach applied math (or perhaps they study the teaching of applied math?), while the latter might be mathematics educators who have gotten [heavily involved with the politics of mathematics education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_wars).

Comment: Obviously, you just need to look up the people on this website with the top reputation.

Comment: @joelreyesnoche applied mathematics educators that teaches applied math topics such as applied statistics, differential equations, etc and are also have influence in industry or organization.  Terrence Tao is not one example, because he is pure mathematician. Gilbert Strang is also not an example

Comment: Why would Gilbert Strang not be an example?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe look at recipients of major prizes in applied mathematics?

Norbert Wiener Prize, William Benter Prize, John von Neumann Lecture, ...

Comment: This is a start.  However, it's possible to be a top applied mathematician without being a top applied mathematics educator.